# Piranha showing my current webpages in the CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

I have a project I have attached Piranha CMS too. That bit worked fine.... However the pages I have already created and the template are not displaying in the CMS edit.

Steps I have done.

1. imported Piranha from guget.
2. Altered webconfig to passive.
3. removed piranha connection section.
4. changed connection to forms.
5. Alter connection string to match sql-server DB.
6. altered the global.config
7. built DB in sql server
8. Built project setup admin and the DB structure built followed.

Like I said it has built ok... But only the standard template. I'm guessing I've ether missed a step or there are steps to go. Can you advise me were to go next?

The webpage site currently just a home page.. The remaining pages are not completed. But if I don't crack this point there is little point continuing.

Comment: I need a little bit more information. When you say that the "pages you have already created", do you refer to pages previously created within Piranha CMS or just regular Controllers/Actions from the MVC-project you added the Piranha CMS NuGet package to?

Comment: the second ..... regular Controllers/Actions from the MVC-project you added the Piranha CMS NuGet package too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add the pages into Piranha through the manager interface, then use the Permalink as the argument to fetch the Piranha managed content from Piranha. I don't think Piranha will parse your view/controller/routes and automatically import them into the site definition.

I use Piranha in my views like this;

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)Model.CMSData.Properties.WebSiteTitle, "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

I embed the CMS data into my model based on the examples in the Getting Started section;

```
public object CMSData = Piranha.Models.PageModel.GetByPermalink("my-permalink") ;
```

This enables me to weave in CMS content to my Model and then use it inside my View.

Comment: I didn't think it would be that easy.......... I will try what you suggested .............cheers Phillip!